# Calculating explained_variance_score, result are different between manual method and function calling

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

According to the formula in official page
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#explained-variance-score,  in order to calculate following EVS for the data set:

```
y_true = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] y_pred = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Manually: `evs = 1 - var(y_true - y_pred)/var(y_true) = -11.5`

Using code: `evs = 1`

```
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score

y_true = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_pred = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

explained_variance = explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Why is the result different?

Comment: It seems something is wrong with your var function, var() -> (standard dev)^2. Assuming the two arrays provided are numpy arrays their subtraction would lead to -5, -5, -5, -5, -5 which has a standard dev of 0. similarly 1,2,3,4,5 has a standard dev of 2. The calculated evs should be 1- 0/2 which is of course 1 not -11.5. Can you pls show your code for var()

Comment: Ok. I am cheated by AI

Comment: huh? Are you using numpy.var(), cause that works 
import numpy as np
y_true = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
y_pred = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
val = 1 - np.var(y_true - y_pred)/np.var(y_true)